# C# All rows from MySQL query not going into datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datagridview

Im trying to fill a DataGridView with the results from a MySql Query however they are not all going in. Here is my code:

```
try
{
                conn.Open();
                player_search = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM admin;", conn);
                reader = player_search.ExecuteReader();

                int counter = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                        player_list[0, counter].Value = reader.GetString(0);
                        player_list[1, counter].Value = reader.GetString(1);
                        player_list[2, counter].Value = reader.GetString(6);
                        player_list[3, counter].Value = reader.GetString(7);
                        player_list[4, counter].Value = reader.GetString(8);
                        player_list[5, counter].Value = reader.GetString(9);
                        player_list[6, counter].Value = "Remove";

                        counter = counter+1;

                }
            }
```

However it doesnt all go in. It only inserts the first row of the query? Why is it doing this? Im getting no errors?

Comment: Do you have an error? You're doing a try, but no catch? Maybe there is an exception. If so, what is it?

Comment: Nah there is no error at all! :( Ive added break points and Ive seen it loop through all the data that should be returned but it just doesnt seem to come up in the DataGridView? :S

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try to get it using DataSet:

```
public DataTable GetDBDataTable(MySqlConnection dbconnection, string table, string columns = "*", string clause = "")
    {
        MySqlCommand mysqlcmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT " + columns + " FROM " + table + " " + clause +";", dbconnection);
        MySqlDataAdapter mysqlad = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlcmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        mysqlad.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        return dt;
    }

 UPDATE:     player_list.DataSource(GetDBDataTable(...));
             player_list.DataBind();
```

Comment: This works to an extent. It adds the correct amount of rows but inputs no data?

Comment: Try dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString(), and see what it gives with i from 0 to rows.Count()

Comment: I hope I helped you a bit ;) Is player_list a DataGridView? In this case, look for my update

Comment: Yeah you pointed me into the direction as you see my post above :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I had to do a long winded approach but it works!

```
MySqlCommand mysqlcmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM admin;", conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter mysqlad = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlcmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            mysqlad.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            player_list.DataSource = dt;
            int rowIndex = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                int i = 0;

                foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        player_list[0, rowIndex].Value = item.ToString();
                    }
                    if (i == 1) {
                        player_list[1, rowIndex].Value = item.ToString();
                    }
                    if (i == 4)
                    {
                        player_list[2, rowIndex].Value = item.ToString();
                    }
                    if (i == 7)
                    {
                        player_list[3, rowIndex].Value = item.ToString();
                    }
                    if (i == 8)
                    {
                        player_list[4, rowIndex].Value = item.ToString();
                    }
                    if (i == 9)
                    {
                        player_list[5, rowIndex].Value = item.ToString();
                    }
                    player_list[6, rowIndex].Value = "Remove";
                    ++i;
                }
                ++rowIndex;
                i = 0;
            }
```